# Unable to access Rancher UI after installed using docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, rancher

im using docker, so i used rancher/server via this command line `docker run -d --restart=always -p 8080:8080 rancher/server` i checked docker containers (`docker ps -a`)i find this :

```
dc191cba6ce8        rancher/server      "/usr/bin/s6-svscan /"   10 minutes ago      Up 27 seconds       3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   naughty_almeida
```

iptables content :

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:8080
```

it's seem fine, but i can't get access to rancher ui page :

```
http://IP:8080
```

docker logs dc191cba6ce8 :

```
2016-07-19 17:58:55,936 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [1/32] [0ms] [0ms] Loading bootstrap 
2016-07-19 17:58:56,267 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [2/32] [330ms] [329ms] Loading config-defaults 
2016-07-19 17:59:09,243 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [3/32] [13307ms] [12976ms] Loading system 
2016-07-19 17:59:09,410 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [4/32] [13474ms] [166ms] Loading defaults 
2016-07-19 17:59:10,482 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [5/32] [14546ms] [1072ms] Loading types 
2016-07-19 17:59:21,385 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [6/32] [25449ms] [10902ms] Loading system-services 
2016-07-19 17:59:22,058 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [7/32] [26122ms] [673ms] Loading agent-server 
2016-07-19 17:59:22,794 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [8/32] [26858ms] [736ms] Loading allocator-server
```

Comment: do you have a URL to the image you're using on docker hub?

Comment: No, i used just this command : docker run -d --restart=always -p 8080:8080 rancher/server

Comment: docker inspect dc191cba6ce8 | grep IPAddress ==> empty is that fine ?

Comment: Only secondry IP address empty or everything?

Comment: For me it works, but I had to wait a pretty long time before I could access it. It takes a while for the container to start up (and I have an IP, but not a secondary)

Comment: i reinstalled rancher/server and after executing the last command i get this   "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"

Comment: That's normal. Now you just have to wait a bit. This is my last log: `time="2016-07-19T13:16:00Z" level=info msg="Creating schema machine, roles [readonly]" id=1ds20`

Comment: i can't get access using public ip adress

Comment: what is the output of: `curl 172.17.0.2:8080` (container IP) (after waiting a bit, check your logs). Perform this command inside your server

Comment: http://172.17.0.2/ is a private adresse i can't get access from outside

Comment: i got this curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: It was the IP of your container. So you have to perform that command on the same place as where you started your container (inside the server). If you've restarted your container you have to recheck that IP with the grep command you described above. With the curl you try to check if you're container is working fine (without using the port mapping) so really inside the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117739/discussion-between-lorenzvth7-and-ahmed-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEBUG (summary of all the comments/chat): 
First we checked if it was an port-mapping issue:

```
docker inspect dc191cba6ce8 | grep IPAddress
```

Which gave an IP back: `172.17.x.x`
When he was able to `curl 172.17.x.x:8080` with an output:
this must return something like:

```
{"type":"collection","resourceType":"apiVersion","links":{"self":"http://172.17.0.6:8080/","latest":"http://172.17.0.6:8080/v1"},"createTypes":{},"actions":{},"data":[{"id":"v1","type":"apiVersion","links":{"self":"http://172.17.0.6:8080/v1"},"actions":{}}],"sortLinks":{},"pagination":null,"sort":null,"filters":{},"createDefaults":{}}
```

So first we thought about a port mapping problem. But than after rechecking the logs I saw there were problems with the container startup:
The output of `docker logs dc191cba6ce8` showed:

```
2016-07-19 17:58:55,936 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [1/32] [0ms] [0ms] Loading bootstrap 
2016-07-19 17:58:56,267 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [2/32] [330ms] [329ms] Loading config-defaults 
2016-07-19 17:59:09,243 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [3/32] [13307ms] [12976ms] Loading system 
2016-07-19 17:59:09,410 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [4/32] [13474ms] [166ms] Loading defaults 
2016-07-19 17:59:10,482 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [5/32] [14546ms] [1072ms] Loading types 
2016-07-19 17:59:21,385 INFO    [main] [ConsoleStatus] [6/32] [26858ms] [736ms] Loading allocator-server
```

And there it stopped. So there were problems with the container startup. This was caused because the server had only 512MB of RAM.
On [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/rancher-server/) are some prerequisitions for running the ranger container:

```
RAM: 1GB+
```

So after creating a bigger server (or doing it locally) it was able to start the container in a proper way and to access the console in the browser.

Comment: Thank's for your time

Answer (score 0):

Just type dockerhost:{here 443} in browser , and if you are using proxy then disable it.